# Dynamic sql query for broken hours data

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Consider a table named "Books" every one hour new entry will be created in UTC format. I want to fetch last 24 hours data (24 entries) in my local timezone.

I tried this

```
select * from books where created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR);
```

How do I fetch records at runtime for the past 24 hours without setting timezone in mysql? Also the created data comes under three different id's, i need the data belonging to id=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**EDITED**) Try this :

```
   select * from books
   where DAYOFMONTH(DATE(created_at))<>DAYOFMONTH(NOW())
   order by DATE(created_at) desc
   limit 24;
```

Now If you want to change the Time zone, for a session use this query :

```
   SET GLOBAL TIME_ZONE = 'ASIA/CALCUTTA'
```

But the only disadvantage is you have to write it every time you restart MySQL.

To change it permananently, Put the following in your mysql server configuration (e.g. my.cnf):

```
   default-time-zone=ASIA/CALCUTTA
```

And the only last last option left is conversion in query itself :

```
    select convert_tz(created_at,'UTC', 'ASIA/CALCUTTA ') MyTimeZone from books
    where DAYOFMONTH(DATE(created_at))<>DAYOFMONTH(NOW())
    order by MyTimeZone desc
    limit 24;
```

Comment: Thanks but this filters the past 24 hours data including data of today. I need only the values of yesterday all the 24 entries excluding today's data

Comment: Thank you it works. But the format is in UTC i need IST.

Comment: You have to use CONVERT_TZ() function in your select statement to get your desired TIMEZONE. See this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: Is this correct ? select * from books where DAYOFMONTH(DATE(created_at))<>DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) && convert_tz('2015-03-04 12:00:00','GMT', 'Asia/Calcutta') 
order by DATE(created_at) desc limit 24;

Comment: Thanks this worked. How will you sum the value of a particular day say there are three value for a single day. The summed value for all the days separately in a month should be listed. I used Group by mon still couldnt fetch clear list.

Comment: @Pinklin, assuming you have 'Value' column in your book table for all the dates then you can try this query : select  temp.d , sum(temp.v) 
from (select DAYOFMONTH(DATE(created_at)) d , month(DATE(created_at)) m,value v from books)  temp
where temp.m= your_month_number
group by temp.d;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR);
```

Comment: @Pinklinpink just remove equal to operator and try

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment on Sagar Joon answer but I cannot so I am adding separate one:

```
select * from books
where DATE(created_at) < date(now())
order by DATE(created_at) desc
limit 24;
```